# Missing Sized.unapply

Tags: scala, shapeless

In `object Sized` (in "shapeless/sized.scala") there is `unapplySeq`, which unfortunately doesn't provide static checking. For example code below will fail at runtime with `MatchError`:

```
Sized(1, 2, 3) match { case Sized(x, y) => ":(" }
```

It would be better if there was `unapply` method instead, returning Option of tuple, and concrete shape of tuple was constructed according to size of Sized instance. For example:

```
Sized(1) => x
Sized(1, 2) => (x, y)
Sized(1, 2, 3) => (x, y, z)
```

In that case previous code snippet would fail to compile with `constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type`.

Please help me implement `unapply` for `object Sized`. Is this method already implemented anywhere?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely possible (at least for `Sized` where `N` is less than 23), but the only approach I can think of (barring macros, etc.) is kind of messy. First we need a type class that'll help us convert sized collections to `HList`s:

```
import shapeless._, Nat._0
import scala.collection.generic.IsTraversableLike

trait SizedToHList[R, N <: Nat] extends DepFn1[Sized[R, N]] {
  type Out <: HList
}

object SizedToHList {
  type Aux[R, N <: Nat, Out0 <: HList] = SizedToHList[R, N] { type Out = Out0 }

  implicit def emptySized[R]: Aux[R, Nat._0, HNil] = new SizedToHList[R, _0] {
    type Out = HNil
    def apply(s: Sized[R, _0]) = HNil
  }

  implicit def otherSized[R, M <: Nat, T <: HList](implicit
    sth: Aux[R, M, T],
    itl: IsTraversableLike[R]
  ): Aux[R, Succ[M], itl.A :: T] = new SizedToHList[R, Succ[M]] {
    type Out = itl.A :: T
    def apply(s: Sized[R, Succ[M]]) = s.head :: sth(s.tail)
  }

  def apply[R, N <: Nat](implicit sth: SizedToHList[R, N]): Aux[R, N, sth.Out] =
    sth

  def toHList[R, N <: Nat](s: Sized[R, N])(implicit
    sth: SizedToHList[R, N]
  ): sth.Out = sth(s)
}
```

And then we can define an extractor object that uses this conversion:

```
import ops.hlist.Tupler

object SafeSized {
  def unapply[R, N <: Nat, L <: HList, T <: Product](s: Sized[R, N])(implicit
    itl: IsTraversableLike[R],
    sth: SizedToHList.Aux[R, N, L],
    tupler: Tupler.Aux[L, T]
  ): Option[T] = Some(sth(s).tupled)
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val SafeSized(x, y, z) = Sized(1, 2, 3)
x: Int = 1
y: Int = 2
z: Int = 3
```

But:

```
scala> val SafeSized(x, y) = Sized(1, 2, 3)
<console>:18: error: wrong number of arguments for object SafeSized
       val SafeSized(x, y) = Sized(1, 2, 3)
                    ^
<console>:18: error: recursive value x$1 needs type
       val SafeSized(x, y) = Sized(1, 2, 3)
                     ^
```

As desired.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `.tupled` on the `Sized` to get a statically-checked unapply?
e.g.

```scala
val (a, b, c) = Sized(1, 2, 3).tupled
```

Comment: Thank you! Would `val Sized(a, b) = Sized(1, 2, 3)` fail to compile?

Comment: Looking into the code I don't really see `Sized.unapply` https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/shared/src/main/scala/shapeless/sized.scala

Comment: Note that for this `val Sized(a, b, c) = Sized(1, 2, 3)` to work, you need only `unapplySeq`. Initially, I asked how to make the wrong code `val Sized(a, b) = Sized(1, 2, 3)` fail to compile.

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I guess you could convert it to a tuple first to get that typechecking: e.g. `val (a, b, c) = Sized(1, 2, 3).tupled` - without needing to write that to go through an HList to get there?